# css animation rotate and translate doesn't work together

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying out the css animation using @keyframes, however the css Transform rotate and translate properties aren't working together.

Please advise on what has gone wrong here. Thanks!!

You can check the code on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdzwZB

following is my @keyframes code:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(10px);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(125px);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Comment: Combine the transforms into a single property. CSS declarations are not additive. The latest overrides the former.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to apply multiple `transforms` is to simply place them all in one `transform` property, with each transform separated by a space:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(10px) rotate(0deg);
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(125px) rotate(360deg);
    color: green;
  }
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/NNwVBj)